# Customize My Account pages on Community site

Tags: community, customization

Is it possible to customize my account page in salesforce community site with VisualForce and Apex? We are looking to be able to customize the page to allow a member to view their profile information, social activity and other member related information (membership type, member ID, date joined, etc, next payment date, etc).

I came across this document, where it says that:
1) Out-of-the-box RSS feeds, analytics tracking, and custom portal profile pages aren’t available
2) Custom change-password pages aren’t available

Here is the document:
http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf

I know you can customize / add pages with VisualForce and Apex but I am new to Salesforce and Force.com communities and it is still not very clear what is possible and what is not.

If there is no way to customize member pages, then we are looking to have members link to another site (through Single Sign-On) where they can view/update the necessary information but that may break the user experience.

Looking for advice.

Thanks!